# Android Invert a Bitmap at Runtime

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to invert a bitmap by using a Paint ColorFilter
I used this link as a reference:
http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg47520.html

but it has absolutely no effect - bitmap is drawn normally can you tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Define float array:

```
float invert [] = { 
        -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
        0.0f,  -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
        0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 
        1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f 
};
```

Setup Paint in constructor

```
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(invert); 
    invertPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
```

Reference in Draw() method

```
c.drawBitmap(Bitmap, null, Screen, invertPaint);
```

EDIT: I was able to get it to work by having the paint assignment in the draw statement:

```
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(invert); 
invertPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm)); 
c.drawBitmap(rm.getBitmap(DefaultKey), null, Screen, invertPaint);
```

but now it renders really slow (probably because its setting up a complicated matrix every single frame) ...is there a reason it works when it's in the same method?

EDIT2:
NEVERMIND!!! Lol, the issue was that I had two constructors and I was only configuring the colorfilter in one of them...the proccess is still very CPU intensive and causes framerate issues

Comment: That's a pretty weird matrix for color inversion. Is it supposed to be 5x4?

Comment: not sure what it means but it works...but it's slow, probably worth it just to save an inverted bitmap and swap them :/

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread.

However: The Matrix is not good for inversion of anti-aliased images with transparency.

Should be:

```
float invert[] =
{
-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 
0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 
0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
```

Comment: That's wrong. You do not want alpha channel to alter red, green, blue channels (second to the last column). The right matrix is given as an example in documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html